# Tridion Publishing Service Stops after server restart

Tags: 2011, publishing

Whenever I restart tridion server, Publishing service stops, It is configured to run automatic with tridion administrator account.

Is there any way to check why this service stops running? All other services run normally. I have to start this service manually after every server reboot.

I found following information in the event logs

```
The Tridion Content Manager Publisher service depends on the Tridion Content Distributor      Transport Service service which failed to start because of the following error: 
After starting, the service hung in a start-pending state.
```

all services are configured to start "Automatic"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

as mentioned in your error. Publishing service is waiting for other dependent services to be start. 
Are following services configured to be delayed start?

- Tridion Content Distributor
- Transport Service

another thing is this error seems to be related to OS not Tridion. so please check for windows configuration and any hotfix.
i found following article for it. if it does't resolve please google for other fixes or put question on server fault or SO

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319127

Answer (score 4):

The way to check why the service stops is to look in the Event Viewer log.  You should see an error message in there with a stack trace.  Once you have that, Google for the answers around the error message, or if you're still stuck, then paste the error here and we'll try to help.

Comment: question updated with more information.